# jquery.append() - only the last element of my list is appended, previous ones are erased

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a page like this :

```
<div id="daysTable">
    <div id="day0" class="day"></div>
    <div id="day1" class="day"></div>
    <div id="day2" class="day"></div>
    <div id="day3" class="day"></div>
    <div id="day4" class="day"></div>
    <div id="day5" class="day"></div>
    <div id="day6" class="day"></div>
</div>
```

and some javascript to fill my calendar like this

```
function getWeek(){
    $.getJSON("/getWeek",function(events){
        var eventHeight = $("#hoursTable > div").height();
        var eventWidth = $("#daysTable > div").width();
        var startWeek = events[0]// timestamp of the start of the week
        for(var i = 1; i < events.length; i ++){
            $(".day").empty();
            var startHour = (events[i].startDate - startWeek)/3600
            var duration = (events[i].stopDate - startWeek)/3600 - startHour
            var dayStart = Math.floor(startHour/24);
            var startHour = startHour - dayStart * 24
            divEvent = $('<div id="event'+events[i].idEvent+'"/>')
                .width(eventWidth-2)
                .height(duration*eventHeight)
                .css("border","1px solid black")
                .css("margin-top",startHour*eventHeight)
                .html(events[i].name);
            divEvent.appendTo("#day"+dayStart);
            console.log(divEvent);
        }
    });
}
```

my problem being : events contain 3 element I'd like to display but only the last is displayed.
If I stop my "for" at the first iteration I can see the first div appended, but it seems that if my loop goes for three iteration the two previous are deleted. 
The console.log() display some "not-anymore" existing element.
Any idea ?

Comment: You may want to avoid setting styles like borders and margins directly in your javascript as these can change if the design ever changes.  Instead, use addClass() to add classes to your elements and then let an external CSS file dictate the look of the calendar.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Inside your loop you're calling `$(".day").empty();` which is erasing any added in previous iterations...you need to move that outside/before the `for` loop so it doesn't do this anymore.

So this:

```
    for(var i = 1; i < events.length; i ++){
        $(".day").empty();
```

Should be this:

```
    $(".day").empty();
    for(var i = 1; i < events.length; i ++){
```

Comment: damn, thinking it took half of my day -_-'

thanks guys, i should take a pause now

Answer (score 3):

By calling `$(".day").empty();` at the top of the loop, you're removing all of the events before you add each new one.

You need to move that line before the `for` loop.

Answer (score 0):

can we see the returned structure of your `"/getWeek"` json....

cause I think the issue is that in `function(events){...}`, `events` is not an array...

I think you should have something like `events.data.length`, then `events.data[i].somevariable`